# Create a database in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio then disappear; why? How to prevent that?

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-studio

I repeated this process about a hundred times.

From scratch:

I created a new website in Visual Studio Express 2013 "ASP.NET Empty Web Site".
Then created an ASP.NET Folder "App_Data".

I switched to Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2012.
**Connect to Server**
   Server name: (LocalDB)\v11.0
   Authentication: Windows Authentication

Right-click the Databases folder and chose "New Database..."
Database name: MyData
Owner: `<default>`
Path: *path to the App_Data folder that I created in Visual Studio.*

From Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio I created one table without problems.
I can see the Visual Studio updated with the Database in App_Data folder.

I closed Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, and Visual Studio.
I reopened Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, and Visual Studio.

The Database "MyData" disappeared from Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio!!!.
But it still exist in Visual Studio.

It is expected to be still exist in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.
So why it disappeared from Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio???
How to prevent that from happening?

Comment: Is this SQL Express of full SQL Server?

Comment: @simonatrcl How to know that?

Comment: @simonatrcl I got it: Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Express LocalDB edition.